# Tratar Retorno de Action em Formato JSon

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net

Colegas Devs, tenho uma aplicação em C# e ASP.NET com uma Action que devolve um array em JSON. Quando devolvo apenas uma string consigo tratar com javascript agora, quando devolvo um array não sei como tratar no javascript.

Segue minha Action:

```
        public ActionResult ListaAcessoUsuario(int codEqpto, string login)
    {
        var acessoDao = new AcessoDAO();
        var acessos = acessoDao.ListaAcessoUsuario(codEqpto, login);

        return Json(acessos);
    }
```

Segue meu Html:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Hora Inicio</th>
        <th>Hora Fim</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Dias Úteis</td>
        <td id="HrIniU"></td>
        <td id="HrFinU"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sábados</td>
        <td id="HrIniS"></td>
        <td id="HrFinS"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Domingos</td>
        <td id="HrIniD"></td>
        <td id="HrFinD"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Feriados</td>
        <td id="HrIniF"></td>
        <td id="HrFinF"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function atualizaCampos(Eqpto, usuario) {
    var url = "@Url.Action("ListaAcessoUsuario", "Acesso")";
    $.post(url, { codEqpto: Eqpto, login: usuario }, atualiza);
}

function atualiza(acessos) {
    //aqui quero pegar o retorno da Action que é um array e exibir na tabela                    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode renderizar o corpo da tabela com o conteudo, algo assim:

```
function atualizaCampos(Eqpto, usuario) {
    var url = "@Url.Action("
    ListaAcessoUsuario ", "
    Acesso ")";
    $.post(url, {
        codEqpto: Eqpto,
        login: usuario
    }, function(data) {
        atualiza(data);
    });
}

function atualiza(data) {
    $('tbody').empty();
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        $('tbody').append('<tr><td>Dias Úteis</td><td>' + item.hinicio + '</td><td>' + item.hfim + '</td></tr>');
    });
}
```

Comment: É isso mesmo Lucas. Muito obrigado!